# Find logged on user remotely using WMI vb.net 2017

Tags: vb.net, networking, wmi

I have been making an app with a button to stop and restart a process then a service remotely.
Before it performs these tasks it will ping the hostname that you input to a textbox and, if it is online it will then resolve the ip into another text box

The i want it to grab the logged on user of the first textbox (txtWS) and display it in a label

The ping works fine and the conversion to IP works fine but when i try to grab the logged on user it never works i have played with the code lots and looked at some questions on here (even adopted some of the code) and still i am unable to get this to work can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong please?

this is the code i have:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Management
```

Button code:

```
If txtWS.Text.Length <> 0 Then

            ConnectWSButton.Enabled = True

            Console.Text &=
            "WS/Host: " & txtWS.Text & vbCrLf

            pingSender.SendAsync(txtWS.Text, Nothing)
        Else
            Console.Text = "Unable to Ping Hostname or Workstation! Please try again, or try via IP Address." & vbCrLf & "Error: " & MsgBoxStyle.Critical & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try
            'Get IP Address of the Host
            Dim Hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(txtWS.Text)
            Dim ip As IPAddress() = Hostname.AddressList

            'Put IP inside txtIP
            txtIP.Text = ip(0).ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Unable to Ping Hostname or Workstation! Please try again, or try via IP Address." & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        'Get logged on user
        Dim MyObjSearcher As System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
            Dim MyColl As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection
            Dim MyObj As System.Management.ManagementObject
            Dim MyMgtScope As System.Management.ManagementScope
            MyMgtScope = New System.Management.ManagementScope("\\" & txtWS.Text)
            'MyMgtScope = New System.Management.ManagementScope("\\" & txtWS.Text & "\root\cimv2")
            Try
                MyMgtScope.Connect()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.Text += "The RPC Server is unavailable" & Environment.NewLine
                Exit Sub
            End Try

        Try
            MyObjSearcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(MyMgtScope.Path.ToString,
                    "Select * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
            ' Execute the query
            MyColl = MyObjSearcher.Get

            ' Display logged on user if configuration option checked
            UsernameLabel = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("UserName") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            MyObjSearcher = Nothing
            MyColl = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' An error occured getting data, display what we did get
            UsernameLabel.Text = "Unable to retreive information!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            Console.Text += "Unable to get logged on user" & Environment.NewLine
        End Try

        'Kill PNC Application
        Dim Computername As String = txtWS.Text
        Dim colProcesses As ManagementObjectSearcher
        Dim colObserver As New ManagementOperationObserver
        Dim refProcess As ManagementObject
        Dim sProcess As String = "PNC"
        Dim options As ConnectionOptions
        options = New ConnectionOptions()
        options.Username = "User"
        options.Password = "Passwords"

        colProcesses = New ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name =   PNC.exe")
        colProcesses.Scope = New ManagementScope("\\" & txtWS.Text & "\root\cimv2", options)
        Try
            colProcesses.Scope.Connect()

            If colProcesses.Get.Count = 0 Then

            Else
                Try
                    For Each refProcess In colProcesses.Get

                        refProcess.InvokeMethod(colObserver, "Terminate", Nothing)

                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.Text = Environment.NewLine & ex.Message
                End Try


            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MSDN example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CCS-LABS-WMI-Getting-5337e2a7) you should be able to loop through the results of the Get Method from the ManagementObjectSearcher instance:

```
For Each objResult As ManagementObject in MyObjSearcher.Get()  
    Console.WriteLine("Antecedent: {0}", queryObj("Antecedent"))
    Console.WriteLine("Dependent: {0}", queryObj("Dependent"))
Next
```

An adaptation in VB.Net from [this more complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458298/341762) shows how to use the Antecendent object:

```
For Each objResult As ManagementObject in MyObjSearcher.Get() 

    Dim objAntecedent As New ManagementObject()
    Dim objObjectPath As New ManagementPath(CType(objResult("Antecedent"), String)) 

    objAntecedent.Path = objObjectPath;
    objAntecedent.Get();

    UsernameLabel.Text += objAntecedent["Domain"] & " " & objAntecedent["LocalAccount"] & " " & objAntecedent["Name"] & " | "

    'Other attributes that can be retrieved: Caption, Description, SID, SIDType, Status, and InstallDate.

Next
```